# how to bind a C++ function to a xaml text textblock property

Tags: c++, xaml, binding, uwp

I have to learn to code on UWP (it's my first steps with windows 10 and VS), so I try to do something really basic : changing a textblock from some C++ function.

Technically my project is quite simple : I opened a new visual C++ > Windows > universal > blank App
I added a textblock to MainPage.xaml :

```
<Page
    x:Class="App4.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App4"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="49,46,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="WHAT I WANT TO BIND" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

and I try to figure how to bind the textblock. I try several ways, all failed. For example, I add a class TestBindMe :

*TestBindMe.h*

```
#pragma once
namespace App4
{

ref class TestBindMe sealed
{
public:
    TestBindMe();
    property Platform::String^ MySuperString
    {
        Platform::String^ get() {
            return this->mySuperString_;
        }
    }

private:
    Platform::String^ mySuperString_;
};

};
```

*TestBindMe.cpp*

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "TestBindMe.h"

namespace App4
{

TestBindMe::TestBindMe()
{
}

};
```

and I try to build it after editing `Text="WHAT I WANT TO BIND"` for `Text={x:Bind TestBindMe.get}`

I got that output :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: App4, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  App.xaml.cpp
1>  MainPage.xaml.cpp
1>  TestBindMe.cpp
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\app4\app4\testbindme.cpp(1): fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "pch.h"' to your source?
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: If it's anything like WPF with C#, I would expect `{Bind MySuperString}` is enough given an instance of `TestBindMe` as the data context.

Comment: @chris I got `Bind is not supported in a Windows Universal Project`

Comment: Sorry, `{x:Bind MySuperString}`. I'm assuming that works mostly the same as regular WPF, but I'm just throwing it out there in any case.

Comment: @Chris : I got `Invalid binding path 'MySuperString' : Property 'MySuperString' can't be found on type 'MainPage'`

Comment: `{x:Bind ...}` only works with properties declared in the same class (e.g. MainPage here). You typically have a property called ViewModel (which would here be of type TestBindMe), and write the binding like `{x:Bind ViewModel.MySuperString}`. Alternatively you could set the MainPage's DataContext property to an instance of TestBindMe, and use a regular Binding, like `{Binding MySuperString}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Clemens said, **`{x:Bind}`** uses the page or user control itself as a default source.

> It will look in the code-behind of your page or user control for properties, fields, and methods. To expose your view model to **{x:Bind}**, you will typically want to add new fields or properties to the code behind for your page or user control. Steps in a property path are delimited by dots (.), and you can include multiple delimiters to traverse successive sub-properties. Use the dot delimiter regardless of the programming language used to implement the object being bound to.

So we can add a property in `MainPage`'s code-behind for `{x:Bind}`. And please note that

> For C++/CX, **{x:Bind}** cannot bind to private fields and properties in the page or data model – you will need to have a public property for it to be bindable.

For more info, please see [{x:Bind} markup extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension).

So I changed your *TestBindMe.h* like following

```
namespace App4
{
    public ref class TestBindMe sealed
    {
    public:
        TestBindMe();
        property Platform::String^ MySuperString
        {
            Platform::String^ get() {
                return this->mySuperString_;
            }
        }
    private:
        Platform::String^ mySuperString_ = "My Bind Test";
    };
}
```

And in *MainPage.xaml.h*, add a public property named "ViewModel" whose type is `TestBindMe`:

```
#include "MainPage.g.h"
#include "TestBindMe.h"

namespace App4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MainPage sealed
    {
    public:
        MainPage();
        property App4::TestBindMe^ ViewModel;
    };
}
```

Then in *MainPage.xaml.cpp*, initialize the `ViewModel`:

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ViewModel = ref new TestBindMe();
}
```

After this, we can use `{x:Bind}` in XAML like `Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MySuperString}"`

This is a simple sample and you can find the official [x:Bind sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlBind) on GitHub.

Comment: I do *not* forget your answer, but I had, and may have, to solve some other problems before coming back on this one...

Comment: @TheUnholyMetalMachine Never mind. Please feel free to come back at any time.